# Fresnel function and finding its maxima (local maxima)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have this one problem in my Calculus textbook which consists of finding all of the local maxima of the Fresnel function : $S(x)= \int_0^x\sin(\pi x^2/2) \ dx$

I solved for the critical points of the derivative $S'(x)=\sin(\pi x^2/2)$ and found out that there are two local maximums at $x = -2$ and $x = \sqrt2$.

My question is : Since I'm working with a sinusoidal function (which means that it's constantly repeating itself on a period) how should I denote my answer?

**For example :**
Should my answer resemble something of this sort?
$$x = \{-2+4n,\sqrt2+4n\}$$ where $n\in \Bbb Z$

Moreover, when you graph the derivative of the Fresnel function I see that the period is gradually shrinking so I wonder how this will affect the answer.

P.S. I recently started solving problems that consist of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus so I know nothing more than that.

Comment: you are using the same name for the variable of $S$ and the integrand, but they are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not going to be adding something regular to $x$ to find the other maxima. You said it yourself; a "gradually shrinking period" means that it's not actually periodic.

Instead, we're going to have maxima whenever $\frac{\pi x^2}{2}$ reaches certain values; one pattern for positive $x$ and one for negative $x$ (Since $S$ is an odd function, switching between positive and negative $x$ interchanges local maxima and local minima).